# Error message "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>"

Tags: swiftui

I am a beginner developer and I am trying to create a TextFieldView with binding an Int and i'm trying to use string interpolation but it's giving me an error: "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding". Am i doing the string interpolation wrong?

```
@State var organizationContactInfo: Int = 0

TextFieldsView(fieldName: "\($profileData.organizationContactInfo)", fieldPlaceHolder: "Organization Info", fieldLeftHolder: "Organization Info")
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove string interpolation from fieldName Argument because fieldName is expecting a binding but string interpolation has change $profileData.organizationContactInfo from binding to string that why it is giving error

```
TextFieldsView(fieldName: $profileData.organizationContactInfo, fieldPlaceHolder: "Organization Info", fieldLeftHolder: "Organization Info")
```

Change TextFieldsView fieldName variable type to this

```
struct TextFieldsView: View {

let fieldName: Binding<Int>

var body: some View{
    //Your Fields here
    EmptyView()
}
}
```